# In_array vs separate values?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got 20+ `divs` and an array with values in array (up to same amount of values in it).

I need to add class if specific value is in array.

```
<div id="div-1" class="<?php if (in_array("16", $array)) { echo 'apple'; } ?>" ></div>
```

**Q:** Is this very expensive? I repeat: 20+ `divs`! Should I split array to 20 separate values and just do a simple `if` check?

As I understand, count of PHP variables or "requests from server" (e.g WordPress `$var = get_post_meta()`) doesn't increase client requests or anything related to loading, bandwidth and speed because PHP is only done in server side, right?

Everything would be so simple if unchecked checkbox returned 0 or anything at all!

---

How I get `$array`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" id="feature-1" value="1"/>
<!-- 20+ more with different id and value +1 with every next -->

<?php
if( isset( $_POST['feature'] ) && '' !== $_POST['feature'] ) {
    $features = $_POST['feature'];
    update_term_meta( $term_id, 'features', $features );
}
```

Comment: How are you generating `$array`?

Comment: I've got an extremly comlicated situation. I've got 20+ checkboxes and while I can't include unchecked checkboxes to array as value 0 for example and while I need to preserve specific order, I have to check if value is in array with every div. I updated my question and added the part how I get `$array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your coding, if you are generating the divs in a loop then it is better to use In_array instead of writing a long switch case, this will increase the scalability of your code , else you can do if check with separate values.